# Should the sentence be in the present perfect or simple past with "last week"?

Tags: present-perfect, simple-past, present-perfect-vs-simple-past

When I was studying English Grammar, I was asked to spot the error

> I've submitted my documents last week.
>      Vs.
>   I submitted my documents last week.

What is wrong/the difference between both of these sentences?

Comment: Welcome to ELU. Please visit [ell.se] -- this Q may be migrated there.

Comment: Questions that simply ask users where is the error, and to correct them is off-topic on EL&U. These questions look like homework tasks and members believe that learners should solve these problems by themselves. BUT sometimes the answer can be tricky, and the person asking may not understand "why" an answer is wrong. In which case they should EXPLAIN their confusion, and demonstrate they have some basic understanding of the problem at hand. Basically, if you show some EFFORT, the community will be pleased to help out.

Comment: The reason why the question was closed is clearly written on the banner, there are also links which explain further.

Comment: Related: [Between Present Perfect and Simple Past, which tense indicates a finished action?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/83593/between-present-perfect-and-simple-past-which-tense-indicates-a-finished-action) and [Present perfect vs. Past perfect for finished actions](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8316/present-perfect-vs-past-perfect-for-finished-actions)

Answer (score 0):

I think both are correct, but the first one emphasise its current status of having been submitted.

Comment: This question is not suitable for EL&U. It belongs on ELL. It is not helpful to answer this sort of question as it is off-topic.