# "James while John had had had had had had had had had had had a better effect on the teacher" Correct Sentence?

Tags: grammaticality

How **"James while John had had had had had had had had had had had a better effect on the teacher"** is Correct Sentence?

Can anyone explain?

Comment: What are you trying to say? Is this the full sentence?

Comment: possible duplicate of [When is it necessary to use "have had"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4870/when-is-it-necessary-to-use-have-had)

Comment: This is full and grammatically correct sentence, I wanna know how it is formed?

Comment: @vs4vijay Not without punctuation- and, not knowing that the context had to do with answering a question on a test, it made no sense.

Comment: General reference: see [James while John had had had had had had had had had had had a better effect on the teacher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_while_John_had_had_had_had_had_had_had_had_had_had_had_a_better_effect_on_the_teacher) wikipedia article

Comment: Vijay where John had where had while while was not grammatically correct. (Or was it? I think you can only use "while" in that position if it means "at the same time as". You can say "Vijay, while John was playing, was studying". But can you say "Vijay, while John was wrong, was correct"?)

Comment: You should start by [searching this very site for that exact sentence](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22James+while+John+had+had+had+had+had+had+had+had+had+had+had+a+better+effect+on+the+teacher%22+site%3Aenglish.stackexchange.com&aq=f&oq=%22James+while+John+had+had+had+had+had+had+had+had+had+had+had+a+better+effect+on+the+teacher%22+site%3Aenglish.stackexchange.com&aqs=chrome.0.57j60.7922j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). Closing, and downvoting, with extreme prejudice.

Answer (score 6):

Not without quotes and punctuation:

> James, while John had had “had,” had had “had had;” “had had” had had a better effect on the teacher.

The context is two students writing a sentence on some graded work, such as:

> Bill had the measles.
>
> Bill had had the measles.

When wanting to know why James scored better, the sentence above explains the reason, although I'd probably explain it like this:

> James scored better because he used the right verb: *had had,* instead of just *had*.

The sentence is not unlike the famous [Buffalo sentence](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2459); it's a contrived example to show how many times a single word can be strung together consecutively in a sentence. Another example is the sign maker who criticizes her own work by saying:

> I should have put more space between *ham* and *and* and *and* and *eggs*.

on a sign that that looks too much like `TODAY'S SPECIAL: HAMANDEGGS`.

---

<sub>(That ‘that that’ that that last sentence has should just read ‘that.’)</sub>

Comment: Can't resist pointing out to the signwriter that in her self-criticism she should have put more space between 'and' and '*and*' and '*and*' and 'and' and 'and' and '*and*' and '*and*' and 'and' and 'and' and 'eggs'.

Comment: @Tim: If only HTML would let her!

Answer (score 3):

JR is right. It's the difference between the past simple & the past perfect.
Put another way: James, where John had used the past simple, had used the past perfect; the past perfect had gained the teacher's approval.

Answer (score 1):

To make it grammatically correct, you have to punctuate it correctly: *James, where John had had 'had', had had 'had had'; 'had had' had had a better effect on the teacher.* For more information on *had had*, try [What does "had had" mean? How does this differ from "had"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/2658/8019) or a grammar book.