# Can the word and be used twice in a sentence in immediate succession

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

I mean the word and is used immediately one after the other.like and and

Comment: Please give an example where you would use the conjunction "and" twice in a row. And... and whether you'd accept the representation of  hesitation, or deep thought.

Comment: Never seen "and and" in a sentence unless it was with a use-mention distinction. Example: The "&" symbol and "and" can be interchangeable sometimes.

Comment: related: [“James while John had had had had had had had had had had had a better effect on the teacher”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/114377/james-while-john-had-had-had-had-had-had-had-had-had-had-had-a-better-effect-on)

Comment: Related. [How should I parse the sentence “Buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo.”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/31163/how-should-i-parse-the-sentence-buffalo-buffalo-buffalo-buffalo-buffalo-buffalo)

Answer (score 1):

Jim opens a cafe selling fish and chips. He has a sign made. It arrives and it says "fishandchips". So he rings up the sign company and says:

> You need to put more space between "fish" and "and" and "and" and "chips"

via [What are some examples of awkward sounding but grammatically correct sentences?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2459/what-are-some-examples-of-awkward-sounding-but-grammatically-correct-sentences)

Comment: +1 Clever. But those "and"s are not the same. Use--mention distinction.

Answer (score 1):

Ordinarily, no, two *and*s do not occur in succession: *and* is used to join two other words or phrases, and to repeat *and* is fundamentally meaningless.

HOWEVER: There are situations in which you may encounter this:

- A speaker may repeat *and* two or more times to cover a gap while she gropes for a word or phrase. Here's an example from a [play](https://books.google.com/books?id=Yf0ll6sHqJEC&pg=PA56&dq=%22and,+and,+and+I%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjav8DDkb3SAhWH7YMKHTOtAHMQ6AEINzAF#v=onepage&q=%22and%2C%20and%2C%20and%20I%22&f=false):

  > I have lived here and, and I have worked hard, and, and, and I have voted and I am still made fun of.
- A speaker may repeat *and* two or more times for rhetorical purposes—to create 'suspense' or to emphasize accumulation. Here's an example from an [autobiography](https://books.google.com/books?id=bxO5qZ_8WGgC&pg=PA41&dq=%22and,+and,+and+I%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjjx_vLkr3SAhUE2IMKHeFPA5Y4ChDoAQglMAI#v=onepage&q=%22and%2C%20and%2C%20and%20I%22&f=false):

  > I didn't even know a baby needed a bassinet. As it turned out, he also needed lots of clothes and bottles and a changing pad and ... and ... and.
- A speaker or writer may use the conjunction *and* with a "meta" use or mention of the word *and*:

  > *And* and *or* are co-ordinating conjunctions.

Answer (score -1):

Some words are able to be repeated, for example:

> I fish fish

Which technically is the ellipsis of the word 'for', as in 'I fish for fish', but is still acceptable in English.

Other examples include:

> if only he had had a chance

This works because the verb 'had' (to have) has two distinct meanings, to have had an experience or possess, and as a past participle to form the perfect, pluperfect, and future perfect tenses.

I can't think of any examples of 'and and' specifically, though.  Searching the [British National Corpus](https://www.english-corpora.org/bnc/) only produces quotes from speech, which is echolalia, as opposed to correct standard English.

Comment: Yes. But that does not answer this question specifically.

Comment: @NVZ how? the question doesn't specify any words in particular.  Simply 'can two words be used in conjunction to one another?'

Comment: it asked about the word "and".

Comment: **like** and and not only and and.

Comment: While 'we fish tuna' may be an acceptable hyponymic usage nowadays, the cognate usage 'we fish fish' sounds outlandish.

Answer (score -3):

'and' is not used twice, but there are some words e.g. 'hot'
It is getting hot and hot (to convey temperature is rising up). There are several words which can be used twice but 'and'.